# invalid scope using oauth2 and server side python

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I'm getting an error when redirecting to google during authentication

The web page has:
Some requested scopes were invalid. {invalid=[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files]}
Learn more
Request Details
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files

On my Drive SDK console, have two scopes enabled:
[https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive]
and
[https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files]

here is the url in question (with stuff redacted):
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=lso&passive=1209600&continue=https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type%3Dcode%26scope%3Dhttps://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files%26access_type%3Doffline%26redirect_uri%3Dhttps://www.myweb.com:8181/oauth2callback%26client_id%1111111.apps.googleusercontent.com%26hl%3Den-US%26from_login%3D1%26as%3D4d3393dc2133b68e&ltmpl=popup&shdf=&scc=1

Answer (score 3):

The scope is:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
```

The other is the URL that you can make API requests to, it is not a scope.